# How to send data from one activity to fragment into another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, uri

I have two classes. One is an activity called 
`"registerProductActivity.java"` that by `ImageView` I pick up a image from gallery (using `Intent.ACTION_PICK`) and I stored it into a Uri (`uri = data.getData()` ) by `"onActivityResult"` method. However, I need send this URI to a fragment into another activity to show this image into a ListvView in this fragment. Any clues guys? I know there are knowable peoples here.

This snippet below is where I pickup image from registerProductActivity.java.

```
....

imagemProduto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_INTENT);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        uri = data.getData(); // declare as global var into this class
        imagemProduto.setImageURI(uri);


    }
}

....
```

After that, I need to send this URI to a fragment into another activity called "MainActivity", this fragment shows a list of products into a listView. In this "MainActivity.java" I use a SlidingTabs that shows two fragments, and one of them has a ListView that shows a custom view to exhibit products. I think that I have to pass this URI to my custom Adapter to set the image up into my listView. So, I don't have any clue to do that. Below has a link to a image to explain better.

[Graphic Relationship between activities and fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lzPc.jpg)

Comment: Is the MainActivity the one that called the RegisterProductActivity or will you will start the MainActivity inside the onActivityResult of RegisterProductActivity?

Comment: Do you have a graphic explication about the activities and fragments relationship.

Comment: Hi Sakura, tks. The MainActivity and RegisterProductActivity is not the same activity. The intent pick action and onActivityResult method is inside RegisterProductActivity. I will post a graphic explication.

Comment: I already posted a graphic explication. Tks

Answer (score 0):

You can send data using Bundle and Intent like below :

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
Bundle extras = mIntent.getExtras();
extras.putString(key, value);
```

and each child fragment of MainActivity can access bundle value directly:

```
Intent mIntent = getActivity().getintent();
Bundle extras= mIntent.getExtras();
String str= extras.getString(key);
```